# Issues booting physical raid disks in vmware 14

Tags: linux, hard-drive, boot, raid, vmware

I'm trying to set a physical raid6 partition on a physical slackware install in VMWare.  mdadm set up goes flawlessly when I boot the machine normally.  But when I boot it in VMWare I get the following errors:

```
The operation on file "\\.\PhysicalDrive3" failed.

If the file resides on a remote file system, make sure that the network connection and the server where this disk resides are functioning properly. If the file resides on removable media, reattach the media.

Select Retry to attempt the operation again.

Select Cancel to end this session.

Select Continue to forward the error to the guest operating system.
```

and

```
VMWare Workstation cannot synchronize with disk before canceling.
Disk \\.\PhysicalDrive3 may be inconsistent.
```

This is in vmware.log

```
2017-10-21T22:19:55.179-04:00| vmx| I125: VMXAIOMGR: "\\.\PhysicalDrive3" : write s=1056768 n=2560 ne=1, fai=0
2017-10-21T22:19:55.179-04:00| vmx| I125: VMXAIOMGR:             v[0]=17A66952000:2560
2017-10-21T22:19:55.179-04:00| vmx| I125: VMXAIOMGR: Retry on write "\\.\PhysicalDrive4" : Access is denied.
2017-10-21T22:19:55.179-04:00| vmx| I125: VMXAIOMGR: system : err=50002 errCode=5 freeSpace=18446744073709551615
2017-10-21T22:19:55.179-04:00| vmx| I125: VMXAIOMGR: "\\.\PhysicalDrive4" : write s=1056768 n=2560 ne=1, fai=0
2017-10-21T22:19:55.179-04:00| vmx| I125: VMXAIOMGR:             v[0]=17A66952000:2560
2017-10-21T22:19:55.179-04:00| vmx| I125: VMXAIOMGR: Retry on write "\\.\PhysicalDrive3" : Access is denied.
2017-10-21T22:19:55.179-04:00| vmx| I125: VMXAIOMGR: system : err=50002 errCode=5 freeSpace=18446744073709551615
2017-10-21T22:19:55.179-04:00| vmx| I125: VMXAIOMGR: "\\.\PhysicalDrive3" : write s=1056768 n=2560 ne=1, fai=0
2017-10-21T22:19:55.179-04:00| vmx| I125: VMXAIOMGR:             v[0]=17A66952000:2560
```

If I select cancel, the VM crashes.  Retry just loops the error and continue will boot the machine but the raid array will have two drives in which are labeled to have failed. (UU__)

I am not convinced the two affected hard drives are faulty.  I've done the smart short test on all of them and they all passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I created raw disk images for VirtualBox with this guide: https://www.serverwatch.com/server-tutorials/using-a-physical-hard-drive-with-a-virtualbox-vm.html, opened VBox in admin mode, and changed the mode of the boot disk to writethrough (although it appears to be in normal mode now?) with the virtual media manager and now it works....for now.

Ok, I don't have the VMWare fix for this, but I'm just as happy to use VirtualBox as I am VMWare.  Whatever gets the job done.